# Batch file day/month/year syntax?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, dos

I can't find a simple breakdown of the batch file syntax for extracting the current day/month/year.

I have the following syntax for declaring a variable used as a directory name;

```
set folder=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%
```

Can anyone shed some light (or post a link) on what the tilde, the double percentage means? I can't seem to fully decipher it from intuition alone.

Comment: You can see this post, there are great examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/windows-batch-script-format-date-and-time

Comment: google "windows batch file syntax"

Comment: @Fredrik, what SO is aiming for is to be at the **top** of that list when you google "windows batch file syntax" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, strangely that is often the case for many technical search-strings :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The double percentage means absolutely nothing. It is simply a result of having two variable expansions side-by-side such as:

```
echo %firstname%%lastname%
     \_________/\________/
      Two separate expansions.
```

The tilde gives you a substring. In your case, `%date:~10,4%` gives you four characters at offset ten of the `date` environment variable (the year in this case since the format is likely `Thu 29/12/2011`, with offsets starting at zero).

If you enter `set /?` at a Windows command pronpt, it will explain all the options for you, including the nifty trick of using negative offsets to extract from the *end* of the string.

However, you should keep in mind that the `date` environment variable format depends on the locale so this simplistic string extraction is unlikely to work across all international versions of Windows (this bit me a couple of years back).

A better solution is to use WMI to get the date components such as on [Rob van der Woude's excellent scripting pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#SortDate5), copied here for completeness:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Dayˆ,Hourˆ,Minuteˆ,Monthˆ,Secondˆ,Year /Format:table') DO (
    IF NOT "%%~F"=="" (
        SET /A SortDate = 10000 * %%F + 100 * %%D + %%A
        SET /A SortTime = 10000 * %%B + 100 * %%C + %%E
        SET SortTime=0000000!SortTime!
        SET SortTime=!SortTime:~-6!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The ~ and %%s are splitting the string (if you just type date into command it shows you the full string).

%date:~10,4%  means get next 4 characters from the 10th character along.

Also watch out for different PCs using different Regional Settings, as they change the order of those characters in the string.

Answer (score 2):

@paxdiablo beat me to it.  Here's a [link to a site that explains how it works](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php#SubStr), with plenty of examples.