# How to print actual time without "a.m", "p.m" and ":"?

Tags: batch-file, time, compare

When I print the actual time in a .bat file I use

```
 TIME /T
```

but the output is like this:

```
 04:30 a. m.   or  14:30 p. m.
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to remove the ":" between the numbers and the a. m. / p. m. from the end of it, so the output looks this way:

```
 0430 or 1430
```

Also, I'd like to know if it's possible to compare that output or the time itself (time /t).  If it's lower than X time, an action is triggered.  I don't know if this code is correct, but something like this:

```
 set /a time=TIME /T     
 if %time%<=(01:00 a. m.) (GOTO 0am)
 if %time%<=(02:00 a. m.) (GOTO 1am)
 if %time%<=(03:00 a. m.) (GOTO 2am)
 if %time%<=(04:00 a. m.) (GOTO 3am)
 if %time%<=(05:00 a. m.) (GOTO 4am)
 if %time%<=(06:00 a. m.) (GOTO 5am)
 if %time%<=(07:00 a. m.) (GOTO 6am)
 if %time%<=(08:00 a. m.) (GOTO 7am)
 if %time%<=(09:00 a. m.) (GOTO 8am)
 if %time%<=(10:00 a. m.) (GOTO 9am)
 if %time%<=(11:00 a. m.) (GOTO 10am)
 if %time%<=(12:00 a. m.) (GOTO 11am)
 if %time%<=(13:00 a. m.) (GOTO 12am)
 if %time%<=(14:00 a. m.) (GOTO 1pm)
 if %time%<=(15:00 a. m.) (GOTO 2pm)
 if %time%<=(16:00 a. m.) (GOTO 3pm)
 if %time%<=(17:00 a. m.) (GOTO 4pm)
 if %time%<=(18:00 a. m.) (GOTO 5pm)
 if %time%<=(19:00 a. m.) (GOTO 6pm)
 if %time%<=(20:00 a. m.) (GOTO 7pm)
 if %time%<=(21:00 a. m.) (GOTO 8pm)
 if %time%<=(22:00 a. m.) (GOTO 9pm)
 if %time%<=(23:00 a. m.) (GOTO 10pm)
 if %time%<=(24:00 a. m.) (GOTO 11pm)
```

If you know an easier way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It would be nice if you FIRST rtm. See `Help set` and `Help if`, or visit [ss64.com/nt](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest first to open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read all output help pages. The last help page is about built-in environment variables for usage in batch files and of course also on command line to which also `DATE` and `TIME` belongs.

The format of `DATE` and `TIME` strings depends on *Windows Region and Language* settings as defined for the user account running the batch file using the environment variables `DATE` and `TIME`.

For that reason it is sometimes better to get date and time string in a region independent format which can be achieved by using the command

```
wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE
```

which outputs for example

```
LocalDateTime=20161227200325.171000+060
```

The date and time string format can be easily seen on looking on this string.

To get from this string just current hour and minute without a colon between in 24 hours format with leading zeros for hours < 10 and minutes < 10 the following batch code can be used:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalTime=%%I"
set "LocalTime=%LocalTime:~8,4%"
echo Local time in format HHMM is: %LocalTime%
pause
```

The output of **WMIC** is split up by **FOR** into 3 strings using `=` and `.` as delimiters as defined with `delims==.`. Of interest for this task is only the second string with date and time referenced with `tokens=2` which is assigned to loop variable `I`. The date/time string in international format is assigned to environment variable `LocalTime`.

The first 8 characters are for the date in format `yyyymmdd` which is not of interest as well as the last 2 characters which are for the current second. Therefore from `LocalTime` just the 4 characters starting from character index position 8 are assigned next to `LocalTime` before outputting the resulting time string.

The output of the batch file for the posted **WMIC** output is:

```
Local time in format HHMM is: 2003
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic OS /?`
- `wmic OS GET /?`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the time formatting you are looking for you will need to use batch scripting string manipulation.  This can be seen in this example [Format date and time in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194991/6655094).

I believe something like this:

```
set time=%time:a. m.=%
```

would remove a. m. from the time.  The trick will be to remove the : since it is part of the string manipulation syntax.

Another good reference for batch string manipulation [DOS - String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

Comment: Thanks man! It's possible to compare a number with ":" in between?

Comment: I do not believe so. The best approach I can think of is to use "set time=%time::=%" after you remove the am pm characters.