# only output first characters of variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a clock in batch, but when typed `echo %time%` the decimal seconds are printed as well. 
which will output:

```
15:18:42,15
```

so i need to get rid of that `,15` but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date and time in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use substing manipulation, as described in `set /?`:

```
echo %time:~0,8%
```

takes 8 characters, beginning at the first character (zero-based counting)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way:

```cmd
for /F "delims=,." %%T in ("%TIME%") do @echo/%%T
```

The [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) iterates once over the time string and splits off the first `,` or `.` and everything after.

---

Anyway, regard that `%TIME%` (as well as `%DATE%`) returns a locale-dependent time (or date) string.

To get the current time in a locale-independent manner, use the [`wmic` command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html):

```cmd
wmic OS get LocalDateTime
```

This returns something like:

> ```cmd
> 20180117151842.150000+000
> ```

Now let us capture this using [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and build our own time string, using [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

```cmd
@echo off
for /F %%D in ('wmic OS get LocalDateTime') do set "DATETIME=%%D"
echo %DATETIME:~8,2%:%DATETIME:~10,2%:%DATETIME:~12,2%
```

And this always returns, independent on the locale and region settings, something like this:

> ```cmd
> 15:18:42
> ```