# .Bat file with date and time in one line

Tags: file, date, batch-file, cmd, copy

I have a search for an easy answer but not found it. 
I have a script that works fine however i would like to add time but it wont give me the result i would like .

```
copy "C:\Temp\ok.txt" "C:\Temp\%date:/=_%_ok.txt"
```

This gives me "**19.02.2018_ok.txt**"

I have tried this:

```
copy "C:\Temp\ok.txt" "C:\Temp\%date~"YYYY-MM-DD":%time~"HH:MM"/=_%_ok.txt"
```

If possible i would like **"2018-02-19 09:59_ok.txt"**

Comment: `:` is illegal in a filename. Is your date/time format precisely "dd.mm.yyyy" and time "hh:mm" ? These formats are variable at the user's whim.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script

Comment: in case you are interested in a [solution independent of locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) to get a valid Date-Time string.

Comment: @Magoo in my first exemple my output gives me what i want, however i would like to add time. "09-58" or "09.58" is ok for me aswell. 
"19.02.2018 09.59_ok.txt" would be fine

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to format and copy with `Get-Date` in PowerShell. When you are confident that the new filename is correct, remove the `-WhatIf`.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile Copy-Item "C:\temp\ok.txt" "C:\temp\$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M_ok.txt')" -WhatIf
```

Line continuation can be used to make it fit better horizontally.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile Copy-Item ^
    -Path "C:\temp\ok.txt" ^
    -Destination "C:\temp\$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M_ok.txt')" ^
    -WhatIf
```