# Execute multiple maven project from MS bat file?

Tags: maven, batch-file

I need to build 3 independent maven projects using a build.bat file (because of tycho aggregation is not an option - see comments on romaintaz answer). I have tried (executed from the build folder - see below):

```
cd ../projectA
mvn clean install -U
cd ..
cd ../projectB
mvn clean install -U
cd ..
cd ../projectC
mvn clean install -U
```

where the folder structure of the projects are:

```
build
  |--> build.bat

projectA
  |--> pom.xml

projectB
  |--> pom.xml

projectC
  |--> pom.xml
```

but only projectA is build projectB and projectC are skipped. Any ideas on how to modify the above batfile so the following project is build if the previous was build successfully?

Comment: are you checking for errors returned from maven in the .bat file? Why do you cd up each time? Are these projects nested inside each other?

Comment: I have updated the example. Checking for errors is secondary - first I need to figure out how to execute a sequence of projects.

Comment: I think maven does `exit`. That's why the batch file finishes after the first `mvn` command and doesn't continue to the next.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the `call` command to execute your mvn processes, like:

```
call mvn clean install -U
```

See [online doc for call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) or

```
help call
```

for further explanations on the call command.

To avoid having all these `cd` commands you can also use the `-f` option to specify the path to your pom, e.g.

```
call mvn -f <path>/projectA/pom.xml clean install -U
call mvn -f <path>/projectB/pom.xml clean install -U
call mvn -f <path>/projectC/pom.xml clean install -U
```

Comment: Thanks that what I am looking for. Now I just need to figure out how to break when one of the projects fails. Is it possible to pipe some output from the maven job to the bat script?

Comment: @tul Maybe you can go with a solution described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable/2340018#2340018)

Comment: Does anyone know the exact reasoning this is required? I know 'call' is used for calling other batch processes which implies to me maven is executing it's commands in a batch as well, is that right?

Comment: @leighmcc Indeed - executing `mvn` means calling the bacht file `apache-maven-x.x.x\bin\mvn.bat`

Comment: What's the use of `-U`?

Comment: @user2918640 -U _"Forces a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories"_ (see `mvn -help`)

Answer (score 8):

As noted above, you need to use "call" to run mvn script as in:

```
call mvn package
```

In order to catch errors you need to use the `ERROR_LEVEL` variable as in:

```
call mvn clean
echo Exit Code = %ERRORLEVEL%
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" exit /b
```

See http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/03/executing-multiple-mvn-commands-from.html for further comments.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you not try to create an **aggregation** parent project?

You seems to have the following structure:

```
someDirectory
  +- projectA
      +- pom.xml
  +- projectB
      +- pom.xml
  +- projectC
      +- pom.xml
```

Simply create a `pom.xml` in the root directory (`someDirectory` in my example), and define the list of modules, which are the `projectA`, `projectB` and `projectC`. This pom will look like:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-aggregation-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>projectA</module>
        <module>projectB</module>
        <module>projectC</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

notes:

- Don't forget to set the `<packaging>pom</packaging>`, as it is not a "real" Java project.
- The name of a `module` should match the name of the directory where the sub-module is hosted.

Now, by doing that, when you run a Maven command on the root directory, Maven will automatically run this command on all the modules. So if you just run `mvn clean install` on the root directory, it will run this command in your three modules.

**Important note:** I am talking here about the [aggregation feature](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation) of Maven. [Not inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance). This means that it is not required that each module has the root project as parent.

Comment: Have tried that. The problem is that a 'target' must be specified in the parent which is resolved for all submodules. Since one of the submodules updates this target it not an option to aggregate.

Comment: I don't see why it would make sense NOT to run 'mvn clean install' from the root - unless of course you just want to build one of the submodules only. But this is not case. I need to build all projects and all submodules for each project.

Comment: @tul I don't understand your problem with the `target` directory. And again, I did not talk about the **parent** feature, but only the **aggregation**. So basically, all the modules are still independent, but the aggregated project will help you to run a command among all your sub-modules. Having an aggregated project does not force you to run all Maven command in this root directory. If you just need to build `projectA`, you can run the Maven command only in this module.

Comment: Its not the target folder but a target platform: http://tycho.sonatype.org/targetplatformmanagement.html

Answer (score 1):

Use 'call' when you want to invoke another batch file in the parent file ,so that control will  be returned to the parent batch file and it will continue execution.

e.g call mvn clean install

Answer (score 1):

I think that using %ERRORLEVEL% will complete +FrVaBe's answer. Originally from [Kunal](http://kunaldabir.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/maven-multiple-builds-from-cmd-file.html)

```
 call mvn -f ProjectA\pom.xml clean install  if not "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto error

 call mvn -DskipTests=true -f ProjectC\pom.xml clean install if not "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto error

 exit

 :error @echo Build Failed pause
```

Comment: in Windows 10 I use:   `if not %ERROR_CODE%==0 goto error`

Answer (score 0):

Since your projects are on the same directory level, you shouldn't navigate up twice.  You're going up via `cd ..` and then again you're going up one level to enter the next project by doing `cd ../projectX`.

Either remove the `cd ..`'s in between or change the cd into your project folder into `cd ./projectX` (current directory instead of parent directory)

By the way, do you really need to use a bat-file for this?  Have you considered a multimodule pom?

Comment: So far I have not be able to do this with a common parent - see above comment. All the projects are submodule projects, so basically I just need to call the parents in the right order - and break if one of the projects fail.

Answer (score 0):

FrVaBe had answered very good. If you would like to keep your code structure, because of some other activities like copying artifacts the the solution would be:

```
cd ../projectA
call mvn clean install -U
echo Do some stuff with artifacts
cd ..
cd ../projectB
call mvn clean install -U
echo Do some stuff with artifacts
cd ..
cd ../projectC
call mvn clean install -U
echo Do some stuff with artifacts
```

Here the most important is **call** function which is used to execute maven build as a kind of subroutine, which ends back into your bat file andd do not exits completely.