# How to build several maven projects on same workspace in one time using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, workspace

**Context**

I've a Eclipse Java Workspace with several projects and I must compile it. To compile each project I set specific run configuration `Run As > Run Configurations... > Maven Build`

**Problem**

I'm expense a lot of time building my projects on Eclipse. To build the projects, I use a different Base Directory for each project, because that I must build one by one and set the specific Base Directory.

**Solution**

Have a way to do it at one time (Build all projects with yours respective Base Directories) by script, Eclipse config. or other option?

Comment: If you want, you can create a parent maven project and all other project as children, you can build by running the parent pom.xml and all other projects will be built automatically. This is the way if I have understood your question.

Comment: Are each project independent or inter linked ?

Comment: @Sachin both.... same projects are linked.

Comment: @Sambit I don't want make changes.

Comment: If your projects are related or part of whole project you can look at Maven Multi-module project. One another alternate choice is to write custom .bat script(for windows) which will simply call `mvn clean install` for respective modules. You can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130312/execute-multiple-maven-project-from-ms-bat-file

Comment: You can use a [_Launch Group_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302032/6505250) for that.

Comment: @howlger on this way, I need create a new `maven configuration` for each project?

Comment: @Augusto Yes, a _Launch Group_ is a container to run other launch configurations sequentially or in parallel. If you want something more generic, how about an Ant or batch/shell script?

Comment: @howlger I didn´t know these potions yet, but I will learn about it, apparentely a ant or script is the best way for my case.

Comment: @Augusto To create an Ant script, create somewhere a file `build.xml`, use the content assist (Ctrl+Space) to get a _Buildfile template_, fill the template with your commands, save it, right-click and choose _Run As > Ant Build_.