# Set output of a command as a variable (with pipes)

Tags: batch-file

Can you redirect the output of a command to a variable with pipes?

I haven't tried much as I haven't been able to think of anything to try, but I have tried one method (with two variations)...

For example:

```
echo Hello|set text=
```

Didn't work, neither did:

```
echo Hello | set text=
```

I know you can do it fairly easily with the `FOR` command, but I think it would look "nicer" with a pipe.

And if you're wondering, I don't have a specific reason I'm asking this other than I'm curious and I can't find the answer.

Comment: Check dolphy's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/batch-files-how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable - if you really don't want to use for you can use a temporary file. There's no way to do it with a pipe, though.

Comment: This problem is described with detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192318/why-does-delayed-expansion-fail-when-inside-a-piped-block-of-code

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1007898/429721 perfected for pipes, stdout/err redirection, multiple executables, output storing and processing value as number and other manipulations... works quite well..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your way can't work for two reasons.

You need to use `set /p text=` for setting the variable with *user input*.
The other problem is the pipe.
A pipe starts two asynchronous cmd.exe instances and after finishing the job both instances are closed.

That's the cause why it seems that the variables are not set, but a small example shows that they are set but the result is lost later.

```
set myVar=origin
echo Hello | (set /p myVar= & set myVar)
set myVar
```

Outputs

```
Hello
origin
```

**Alternatives:** You can use the FOR loop to get values into variables or also temp files.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('echo hello') do set "var=%%A"
echo %var%
```

or (and before you ask, these `>` and `<` at the beginning of the command are not in error).

```
>output.tmp echo Hello
>>output.tmp echo world

<output.tmp (
  set /p line1=
  set /p line2=
)
echo %line1%
echo %line2%
```

or, same, but on one line and one value, also deletes the temp file:

```
>output.tmp echo Hello World&&<output.tmp (set /p line1=)&&del output.tmp
```

**Alternative with a macro:**

You can use a batch macro, this is a bit like the bash equivalent

```
@echo off

REM *** Get version string 
%$set% versionString="ver"
echo The version is %versionString[0]%

REM *** Get all drive letters
`%$set% driveLetters="wmic logicaldisk get name /value | findstr "Name""
call :ShowVariable driveLetters
```

The definition of the macro can be found at
[SO:Assign output of a program to a variable using a MS batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54425285/463115)

Comment: So, there is no way around the limitations without a temp file or the "for" command? Even if there isn't, thanks anyway.

Comment: Obviously you can use `FOR` but then you don't need a pipe. The same apply to temp files

Comment: btw, it appears in my tests that you can only use 1 command in a for statement.  You cannot chain more commands together with &.

Comment: @end-user You can use more than one command, but it's better to combine them with parenthesis `for %%a in (a b c) do (echo %%a <NewLine>echo ----)`

Comment: No, I meant in the evaluation.  But it turns out I can if I escape the & sign: `for /f %%i in ('first command ^&^& second command') do echo result: %%i`

Comment: You tmp file does nto work for me? It writes the correct data to a file for me. But it does not read it back into the variables correctly. I changed my command to `wmic os get osarchitecture`

Comment: Thank you for a complete discussion of the alternatives.  It is unfortunate that the for statement is so obtuse, but it worked for me

Answer (score 15):

The lack of a Linux-like [backtick/backquote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash) facility is a major annoyance of the pre-PowerShell world. Using backquotes via for-loops is not at all cosy. So we need kinda of `setvar myvar cmd-line` command.

In my `%path%` I have a dir with a number of bins and batches to cope with those Win shortcomings.

One batch I wrote is:

```
:: setvar varname cmd
:: Set VARNAME to the output of CMD
:: Triple escape pipes, eg:
:: setvar x  dir c:\ ^^^| sort 
:: -----------------------------

@echo off
SETLOCAL

:: Get command from argument 
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%*") do set cmd=%%b

:: Get output and set var
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`%cmd%`) do (
     ENDLOCAL
     set %1=%%a
)

:: Show results 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo %1=!%1!
```

So in your case, you would type:

```
> setvar text echo Hello
text=Hello
```

The script informs you of the results, which means you can:

```
> echo text var is now %text%
text var is now Hello
```

You can use whatever command:

```
> setvar text FIND "Jones" names.txt
```

What if the command you want to pipe to some variable contains itself a pipe?
Triple escape it, `^^^|`:

```
> setvar text dir c:\ ^^^| find "Win"
```

Comment: What does the `usebackq delims=` part do there?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: `usebackq` specifies to use a linux-like semantics, where a back quoted string is executed as a   command and the output parsed into the `for` variables (here `%%a`).  `delims=x` specifies the  delimiter to be used in parsing (here no delimiters).

Comment: Thx for clarification. I used this pattern to great success in a build tool. This answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 10):

I find myself a tad amazed at the lack of what I consider the best answer to this question anywhere on the internet.  I struggled for many years to find the answer.  Many answers online come close, but none really answer it. The real answer is

```
(cmd <arg> & echo.) >2 & (set /p <var>=)<2
```

The "secret sauce" being the "closely guarded coveted secret" that "echo." sends a CR/LF (ENTER/new line/0x0D0A).  Otherwise, what I am doing here is redirecting the output of the first command to the standard error stream.  I then redirect the standard error stream into the standard input stream for the "set /p =" command.

Example:

```
(echo foo & echo.) >2 & (set /p bar=)<2
```

Comment: I'm sorry to spoil your dreams, but this doesn't work via STDERR, but via a file with the name `2` (check with `dir`)

Comment: Oh.  Thank you Stephan.  It appears I still do not know if it is possible to stream the output from one command to the input of another without a file as an intermediate, apart from the rare except of pipe to more.  It seems odd that in Windows and DOS that more seems one of only a few commands that can have input piped to it.  After hours over the span of over a decade, I am yet to have seen anyone explain this satisfactorily.

Comment: there are a few more commands, that take input through a pipe: more, sort, find, findstr, clip, choice, date, time, diskpart, wmic, schtask, pause and (not verified but probably yes): ftp, telnet, ssh and maybe a few more.

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you for sharing Stephan.

Comment: You have saved me next 10-20 years of looking for this solution!!!

Comment: I recommend adding an UPDATE to this answer with: `(cmd & echo.) >temp & (set /p =)<temp & del temp`.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the output to a temporary file and the read the data from the file after that you can delete the temporary file.

```
echo %date%>temp.txt
set /p myVarDate= < temp.txt
echo Date is %myVarDate%
del temp.txt
```

In this variable `myVarDate` contains the output of command.

Comment: There are already 3 old answers mentioning a tempfile. I can't see any further benefit of your answer?

Comment: It fit to my search, so+1

Answer (score 5):

THIS DOESN'T USE PIPEs, but requires a single tempfile
I used this to put simplified timestamps into a lowtech daily maintenance batfile
We have already Short-formatted our System-Time to HHmm, (which is 2245 for 10:45PM)
I direct output of Maint-Routines to logfiles with a $DATE%@%TIME% timestamp;
. . . but %TIME% is a long ugly string (ex. 224513.56, for down to the hundredths of a sec)

SOLUTION OVERVIEW:
1. Use redirection (">") to send the command "TIME /T" everytime to OVERWRITE a temp-file in the %TEMP% DIRECTORY
2. Then use that tempfile as the input to set a new variable (I called it NOW)
3. Replace

```
echo $DATE%@%TIME% blah-blah-blah >> %logfile%
```

with

```
echo $DATE%@%NOW% blah-blah-blah >> %logfile%
```

====DIFFERENCE IN OUTPUT:
BEFORE:

```
SUCCESSFUL TIMESYNCH 29Dec14@222552.30
```

AFTER:

```
SUCCESSFUL TIMESYNCH 29Dec14@2252
```

ACTUAL CODE:

```
TIME /T > %TEMP%\DailyTemp.txt
SET /p NOW=<%TEMP%\DailyTemp.txt
echo $DATE%@%NOW% blah-blah-blah >> %logfile%
```

AFTERMATH:
All that remains afterwards is the appended logfile, and constantly overwritten tempfile. And if the Tempfile is ever deleted, it will be re-created as necessary.

Comment: This is actually the only solution which worked when I was trying to pass a complex git command, e.g. `git log --pretty=format:%ad_commit_%h -n 1 --date=short`.

Comment: Simple and effective

Answer (score 4):

In a batch file I usually create a file in the temp directory and
append output from a program, then I call it
with a variable-name to set that variable.
Like this:

```
:: Create a set_var.cmd file containing: set %1=
set /p="set %%1="<nul>"%temp%\set_var.cmd"

:: Append output from a command
ipconfig | find "IPv4" >> "%temp%\set_var.cmd"
call "%temp%\set_var.cmd" IPAddress
echo %IPAddress%
```

Comment: Quite skillful. Usually, avoiding temp files is nice, though.