# Advance For loop in Batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

for few days i am trying to write a batch script which can copy a single specific file to all folder and sub-folder in every available drive (C:, D:, E: etc....) in computer.

I am using `tree` command to revile the list of folder and sub-folder on target drive. then I used for loop + tree command to achieve my goal.

here what i try to do

```
set a="tree"
for %%g in (' %a% ' ) do (
  echo %%g
)
```

for now i just print the output of `tree` command using for loop.

Comment: Only `for /f` loops can process commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set output of a command as a variable (with pipes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952295/set-output-of-a-command-as-a-variable-with-pipes)

Comment: Why you don't just use `for ... %%g in ('tree') do (` instead? Do you want the most convoluted code instead of a simple one?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `/R` switch for that. Changing to one directory and then using `for /r` will result in a for-loop that goes through all subdirectories as well.

To get a list of all directories on a device, you can use 
`wmic logicaldisk get deviceid`