# Is it possible to redirect to a file with a name transformed by a pipe program?

Tags: pipe, command-prompt

If you have a program that can transform some input text into an alternative output text via a pipe, can you then redirect output of another command to a filename produced by the first program?

```
echo Hello > source/somedir/somefile.txt | somepipeprogram
```

The above is probably the wrong syntax, the word Hello ends up in .\source\somedir\somefile.txt even if `somepipeprogram` always returns a different filename

I have tested `somepipeprogram` and it does indeed correctly transform into my desired output filename

i.e `echo \source\somedir\somefile.txt | somepipeprogram` will return my alternate filename.

So if `somepipeprogram` was configured to produce 'c:\temp\someotherfilename.txt' from that input, then it would output that using the previous invocation

I thought I had the answer from the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954264/176690, except the variable that has been set doesn't exist once setvar.bat exits

Here is the contents of my secondary batch file

```
SETLOCAL
CALL setvar filename echo %1 ^^^^| somepipeprogram    
ECHO filename var='%filename%' - if showing var='' expansion failed
```

I see setvar display the correct answer but the moment it leaves setvar.bat `%filename%` does not exist

Comment: At the moment I have solved my problem by moving the techniques from setcmdvar directly into the script, its not re-usable but it does work

Answer (score 0):

echo Hello >  `somepipeprogram`

or

echo Hello > $( somepipeprogram )

also depending or your shell.

(I am obviously assuming some Unixy shell like bash here.)

Comment: backward apostroph signs around somepipeprogram

Comment: the backtics still wrote a file called somepipeprogram rather than anything else