# Can not pipe an echo to an input

Tags: batch-file

I just started programming in batch.
I tried to execute the following code in a .bat file, and also in CMD directly.
In either case I receive a blank space.

```
ECHO My name is agent Smith |  SET /P Name="What is your name?"
ECHO Result is %Name%
```

A found this code in a book about batch programming, but does not work.

Somewhere i read that echo is in a different context,
and SET /P only accepst user entered things.

Comment: A pipe initiates a new `cmd.exe` instance for either side, so the variable in the hosting instance is not altered: `echo Test| (set /P VAR=& set VAR)` will return `VAR=Test`, but `echo Test| set /P VAR=& set VAR` will not (given that `VAR` is not initially set)…

Comment: *N. B.:* Would you mind telling us what book you are talking about?

Comment: I tried like you wrote:
`ECHO My name is agent Smith   | (SET /P Name=  & SET Name )`
directly in cmd it gets me:  `Name=My name is agent Smith`

but in a file it does not, I run the file from cmd like c:\User>pipe-1.bat

Comment: The book is:
Batchography: The Art of Batch files programming

Comment: There should be no difference whether the code is directly run in Command Prompt or within a batch file, pipes behave just the same…

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952295/set-output-of-a-command-as-a-variable-with-pipes) stack overflow for a more in depth discussion on what's causing the problem. In short pipe operator evaluates the left and right side in separate threads. This means that `SET /P Name=` sets the environment variable `Name` in its thread's context and not the invoking thread's context. This can more clearly be seen in following example:

```
set name=invokingContext
echo threadContext | (set /p name= & set name)
set name
```

which outputs:

```
name=threadContext
name=invokingContext
```

Assuming you have write permissions, an easy way to get around this limitation is to use temporary files and redirection:

```
echo My name is agent Smith > tmp.txt
set /p Name=What is your name < tmp.txt
echo %Name%
```

Which outputs:

```
What is your name
My name is agent Smith
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this work just fine!
with an additional `DEL tmp.txt` line I do not mak unnacasarry files.

However I still wonder why the first code I tried didn-t work? I mean it is from a book which I assume is not bad. Is it becaouse it was written in 2016?