# How to check PATH variable for java already installed or not in a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a test.bat file where i need to write a script to check PATH VARIABLE for java already installed or not ?

```
 Conditions :-

  1) If yes then 
       a) Check for the java version .
       b) Check for JAVA_HOME env variable :-
           i) if no , create it.
           ii) if yes , get the JAVA_HOME value.
  2) If No then
   set JAVA_HOME to local path (embedded)



 I know the commands like :-
      For version
         -> java -version

      For variable path 
         -> echo %path%

      For Java variable path
         -> echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

But how to write script for these condition  in batch file i.e .bat ?
I'm very new to this so kindly give me your valuable answers or helpful links.

Answer (score 3):

You can check with something like that:

```
@echo off
if defined JAVA_HOME (
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto okJavac
)

echo Java not found
exit 1

%okJavac
echo Java path "%JAVA_HOME%"
rem the end of your script
```

Comment: :I tried your code but after double clicking on the test.bat file but i could see a glimpse of terminal which comes and disappear .Even i checked JAVA_HOME path location and its in right location as what you defined in your code. How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: @Tala : any solutions for this ?

Comment: Start your bat from cmd with K key added : `/K yourfile.bat`

Comment: i tried :okJavac instead of  %okJavac ....and its working .
thanx Tala and Alexxx  :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^"  %%a in ('java -version 2^>^&1') do set "JavaVersion=%%a"
IF NOT DEFINED JavaVersion ECHO no Java installed & GOTO :EOF
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=." %%a IN ("%JavaVersion%") DO SET "sub=%%a"

IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (
    IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME SET "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre%sub%\bin"
) ELSE (
    IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME SET "JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre%sub%\bin"
)

SET "java_home"
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the appropriate [MS guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121170/en) for working with the batch files.
You can check the output of the *java -version*  in the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)