# How do I write a batch that is copying itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to write a batch file, which reads its own code inside a string, then creates a new batch file with the string as content and execute it.

Comment: And where do you want to get with this? No memory?

Comment: are you looking for something like `%0 | %0`

Comment: @radugheorghiu i want to create a selfe replicating batch with an mutation algorithm ofcourse it should have also an algorithm wich prevents a to high number of files and lets it die after a certain number of replications

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink Then it might work. Just try what Nemesis said.

Comment: Quines are related to your question, try a look at [Quines on Dostips](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsQuine.php) and [the forum thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5728)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the content of the started batch file with

```
    type "%~f0"
```

Therefore, try something like

```
    echo off
    type "%~f0" > Test\file.bat
    Test\file.bat
```

However, this script would repeat itself continously (or aborts if the directory Test does not exist). So you need to think about this approach (i.e. using conditional statements).

Comment: this is great, but is there a way to store the code inside a variable before creating the new batch, so i can modify it before?

Comment: Just have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

if not exist newBatchFile.bat (

   echo First execution!

   set "batchFile="
   for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~F0") do (
      set "line=%%a"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      if "!line:~0,1!" equ ")" set "batchFile=!batchFile:~0,-1!"
      set "batchFile=!batchFile!!line!"
      if "!line:~-1!" neq "(" set "batchFile=!batchFile!&"
      for /F "delims=" %%b in ("!batchFile!") do endlocal & set "batchFile=%%b"
)
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   echo !batchFile:~0,-1! > newBatchFile.bat
   newBatchFile.bat

) else (

   echo Second execution!

)
```