# How to kill a CLOSE_WAIT state process preferably by port 80 in WINDOWS with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, kill-process, netstat

*Summary:
Rogue java processes from lingering stopped services preventing service from returning.*

Stopping a java service doesn't kill the java process on occasion, it locks it in a CLOSE_WAIT status endlessly, so port 80 is still being used on the IP when the service attempts to return, thus the service fails to start

Doing a netstat -ano returns the PID of the IP/PORT combination, then I can kill it manually.  I'd like to prevent myself from having to do this.  I'd like to add to our service restart script a section that will kill any port 80 process in the CLOSE_WAIT status.

I can do this in Linux easily enough:

```
$ netstat -anp |\
grep ':80 ' |\
grep CLOSE_WAIT |\
awk '{print $7}' |\
cut -d \/ -f1 |\
grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{1,}" |\
xargs kill
```

But my windows batch scripting skills are pretty sub-par.

Can anyone assist in a windows equivalent to get this done?

Comment: Sounds like it's not really killing the java process, not a port problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have something you could use (run it as a .bat):

```
echo off
netstat -ano | find "127.0.0.1:80" | find "CLOSE_WAIT" > out.txt

FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (out.txt) DO (
    TASKKILL %%I
)

del out.txt
```

It can be done as a single command (without having the .bat file) but I think this is more readable.

**UPDATE**

An improvement of the script shown above, you can avoid using the temporary file by enclosing the piped command in the for loop using single quotes and carets (^) before the pipes simbol (|):

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "127.0.0.1:80" ^| find "CLOSE_WAIT"'
) DO (
    taskkill /PID %%I
)
```

The help of the for /F commands explains it better:

> Finally, you can use the FOR /F command to parse the output of a command. You do this by making the file-set between the parenthesis a back quoted string.  It will be treated as a command     line, which is passed to a child CMD.EXE and the output is captured    into memory and parsed as if it was a file.  So the following example:
>      FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`set`) DO @echo %i

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19443699/3046834) for the caret solution

Comment: OK, I will give this a shot.  Looks promising.  Would there be a way to do this without an output file by chance...?

Comment: I'm find for kill process on port 8020:  C:\Users\stas>netstat -ano | find "127.0.0.1:80" | find "CLOSE_WAIT"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8020         127.0.0.1:21364        CLOSE_WAIT      10104
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8020         127.0.0.1:21368        CLOSE_WAIT      10104

C:\Users\stas>taskkill /PID 10104
ERROR: The process "10104" not found.  What is the problem?

Comment: @Stan Zeez, can you post a new question? It´s hard to read your code written like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
netstat -ano | find "CLOSE_WAIT" > out.txt
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "CLOSE_WAIT"'
) DO (
    taskkill /PID %%I /F
)

del out.txt

netstat -ano | find "TIME_WAITT" > out.txt
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "TIME_WAITT"'
) DO (
    taskkill /PID %%I /F
)
del out.txt

netstat -ano | find "127.0.0.1" > out.txt
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "127.0.0."'
) DO (
    taskkill /PID %%I /F
)
del out.txt

netstat -ano | find "0.0.0.0" > out.txt
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "0.0.0.0"'
) DO (
    taskkill /PID %%I /F
)
del out.txt
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping a large batch script here, could you [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64491271/edit) to provide some explanation of your approach, and what the most relevant commands are? That will help future readers better understand this approach and modify it to meet their needs.