# Windows Batch: command result as command parameter

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

I have a curstom command that is an query language interpretor. And the file contains some queries to execute.

I want to execute this custom command by passing the whole file content as parameter with a single command.

For exemple somethink like  :

```
myCustomCmd %type params.txt%
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch assign output of a program to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("params.txt") do myCustomCmd %%a
```

should draw that line from the file and use it as a parameter for you command.

Had you given us a context, I'd be able to provide more information.

---

Ah - you want "the entire file content" as the parameter - a requirement you edited-in five minutes after I'd posted this response...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "params="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("params.txt") do set "params=!params! %%a"
myCustomCmd %params%
```

That should fix the problem - in the absence of an example `params.txt` file.

Comment: I like to pass the whole file content as parameter at once.

Comment: Sorry for that misstake. Thanks it solve my problem.