# Grep and run a Batch

Tags: linux, batch-file

Is it possible to grep a value then store it in a file via batch file??

Like for example,

```
grep "error 404" Mow*2015.txt | wc -l
grep "error 403" Mog*2015.txt | wc -l
```

Then I want it to put in a batch for it to generate another txt file or other extension.

```
set ARH = * grep for the 404 *
set ARG = * grep for the 403 *

ECHO %ARG% %ARH% >> admin.log
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch assign output of a program to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have installed cygwin or [Windows Services for UNIX](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391).But you can use windows command only to achieve what you want:

```
for /f "delims=" %%# in (
  '"%windir\system32\FIND.EXE%" "error 404" mow*2015.txt' ^| "%windir\system32\FIND.EXE%" /c /v /n ""
) do set "ARH=%%#"

for /f "delims=" %%# in (
  '"%windir\system32\FIND.EXE%" "error 403" mow*2015.txt' ^| "%windir\system32\FIND.EXE%" /c /v /n ""
) do set "ARG=%%#"

ECHO %ARG% %ARH% >> admin.log
```