# Why batch file is not working if executed from python script or if executed by double clicking it?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script which is generating a configuration file after its execution, the configuration file generated has some data inside it. When i execute it from command prompt as follows i get the desired output :

```
C:/> start.bat
```

but if i try to execute from python script as follows or even if i double click and execute it i do get the configuration file but it does not contain any required data it just have '0' inside it:

```
import subprocess as sp
p= sp.Popen("C:/pathtobatch/start.bat",stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

Inside the batch script(start.bat) i am actually executing a python script and retrieving its data to a configuration file as follows:

```
python C:\inetpub\ftproot\sample.py > log.txt
set  myvar =< log.txt
del log.txt
echo %errorlevel% %myvar% >C:\inetpub\ftproot\config.txt
```

I need to execute the batch(start.bat) from the python script and generate the config.txt file having the required data. So, how shall i do that.
Why the start.bat is not working fine if i double click it and why is it working fine if i am executing it from command prompt.

Comment: put `pause` at the end of bat and try double clicking.

Comment: @WhoAmI no it does not woking by adding pause also.:/

Comment: Specify full paths, everywhere. This pointless question which is about configuration of the execution environment is asked over and over again. Specify exactly what you want to happen. `%userprofile%\desktop` will usually be the user's desktop.

Comment: How are you handling the job's stdin/stdout/stderr in the Python?  Are you waiting for the job to complete before exiting the Python program?

Comment: `set  /P myvar=< log.txt`; read _entire_ `set /?` and/or http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: Please read [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) to understand why [JosefZ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) suggested the command __SET__ without spaces around the operators.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you get '0' as it is the value of %errorlevel%?

I found two issues in your case:

1) batch file - can you please update your batch file to something like:

```
for /f %%i in ('python C:\inetpub\ftproot\sample.py') do set myvar=%%i
echo %errorlevel% %myvar% >C:\inetpub\ftproot\config.txt
```

Credit for the idea of setting variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340018/5088142

2) python script - can you please update your python script to be:

```
import os
os.system("C:/pathtobatch/start.bat")
```