# Batch-file - Fetch remote computer variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I've got a VERY big pre-existing batch file that I need to add some logic to run the correct EXE depending on whether it is a x86 or x64 bit machine.  I can't use PowerShell because for some reason they have it pseudo disabled on most of these machines.

What I'm trying to do is use PSEXEC to fetch the system variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE from the remote, then create a local system variable from the output.

If I run this command from a Win10x64 CMD prompt:

```
C:\PsTools>c:\pstools\PSEXEC.exe \\TEST-Win7x86 cmd /c echo ^%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^%
```

I get the correct remote x86 value, but can't do anything with it:

```
x86
cmd exited on TEST-Win7x86 with error code 0
```

.

I tried testing [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable) to get the output into a variable:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('c:\pstools\PSEXEC.exe \\TEST-Win7x86 cmd /c echo ^%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^%') DO set proc=%i
```

I'm getting back the local AMD64 value:

```
cmd exited on TEST-Win7x86 with error code 0.
C:\PsTools>set proc=AMD64
```

.

Anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

-Matt

Comment: Are you aware that you have to double the `%` signs of `for` variables when being used within batch files? Also I think you need to write `^^%%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^^%%` in the `for /F` loop in order to pass the string `^%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^%` over literally...

Comment: You could also avoid the percent sign ambiguity by doing `psexec \\remotepc powershell "$env:processor_architecture"`.  Or you could skip `psexec` and use a remote WMI query.  `for /f %I in ('wmic /node:remotepc os get osarchitecture /value ^| find "="') do set "%I"`

Comment: I use the PowerShell method most of the time, but in this case these computers have something in place preventing PowerShell from working.  I didn't think of using WMIC to fetch it.  I'll remember that for next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After messing with this most of the day, I think I have it figured out shortly after submitting this question.  I had to double-up the carrots for some reason.  I'm not exactly sure why I thought to try it or why it works, but I'm getting the correct output now.

```
C:\PsTools>FOR /F %i IN ('c:\pstools\PSEXEC.exe \\TEST-Win7x86 cmd /c echo ^^%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^^%') DO set proc=%i
```

Output:

```
cmd exited on TEST-KW-O3040MD with error code 0.

C:\PsTools>set proc=x86
```

.

And as aschipfl corrected below, this is the correct context for in the batch script.  Thanks aschipfl!

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('"\\Server\Shared Folder\PSEXEC.exe" \\TEST-Win7x86 cmd /c echo ^^%%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^^%%') DO set PROC=%%i
```

Comment: This can only work in case you execute it in command prompt (`cmd`) directly; in a batch file, you'll need to double the `%` signs of the `for` variable `%i` as I already suggested, and the ones in the `IN ( ... )` part too...

Comment: Well that worked for the command line, but now it's broke in the script.

Running this command:
.
.
`FOR /F %%i IN ('"\\Server\Shared Folder\PSEXEC.exe" \\%CNAME% cmd /c echo ^%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^%') DO set PROC=%%i`

Results in the local AMD64 again.  Doubling up carrots seems to kill it.

If only I knew how the double-carrots properly escaped it in the first place.. :(

Comment: `FOR /F %%i IN ('"\\Server\Shared Folder\PSEXEC.exe" \\TEST-Win7x86 cmd /c echo ^^%%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE^^%%') DO set PROC=%%i` should work...