# Getting the date taken parameter for the image with a name as variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to get the `Date Taken` parameter for an image (identified by `NAME_OF_AN_IMAGE` variable with `PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER` constant) and pass it to the main *batch script*; within the batch script I must use a Powershell instruction (it is not possible to get the `Date Taken` directly by cmd command).

I have to provide a `NAME_OF_AN_IMAGE` variable to the Powershell script and at the same time bypass the restricted execution policy.

Briefly, the date taken for the named image should be returned from the Powershell script and set to the `Date` variable within the batch file.

I have the following lines of commands within the Powershell 'DateTaken.ps1' script:

```ps
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing");

$imagePath = "PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER\NAME_OF_AN_IMAGE.JPG";
$pic=New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $imagePath;
$DATE = $pic.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[0..9];

$strYear = [Char]$date[0],[Char]$date[1],[Char]$date[2],[Char]$date[3];
$strMonth = [Char]$date[5],[Char]$date[6];
$strDay = [Char]$date[8],[Char]$date[9];
$DateTaken = $strYear + "." + $strMonth + "." + $strDay;
```

and within the batch file:

I am not able to run the set of Powershell instructions listed above in order to get to the `$DateTaken`  variable and assign it to Data variable within the batch script.

If I get the set of the above Powershell instructions to return the value of `Data`, I will be able to pass it into the temp.txt file using the grater than sign '> temp.txt' and then read it into the batch file by `set /p Data< temp.txt` command.

Comment: Don't use variable name `date` as this is system-reserved!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch assign output of a program to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)

Comment: I will change the date to the data then.

Comment: As for assigning Powershell output to a batch variable with bypassing execution policy restriction at the same time - I don't have a faintest idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is, that set requires a String and $DateTaken in your script contains an array. The other thing is, that you have to output $DateTaken.

So that's what I did and this script outputs me the date as String.

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing");

$imagePath = "C:\temp\pic2.jpg"
$pic=New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $imagePath

$picDate = $pic.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[0..9]

$strYear = [String][Char]$picdate[0]+[String][Char]$picdate[1]+[String][Char]$picdate[2]+[String][Char]$picdate[3]
$strMonth = [String][Char]$picdate[5]+[String][Char]$picdate[6]
$strDay = [String][Char]$picdate[8]+[String][Char]$picdate[9]
$DateTaken = $strYear + "." + $strMonth + "." + $strDay
$DateTaken
```

Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen

shorter - more powershellway :)

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing");

$imagePath = "C:\temp\pic2.jpg"
$pic=New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $imagePath

$picDate = $pic.GetPropertyItem(36867).value[0..9]

$DateTaken = [char[]]$picdate -join '' -replace '\D','.'
$DateTaken
```

Comment: Constructing the date string can be boiled down to `[char[]]$picdate -join '' -replace '\D','.'`

Comment: The only problem I have is to pass the picture name variable to the powershell script, i.e with the line: $imagePath = "PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER\NAME_OF_AN_IMAGE.JPG";

Comment: PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER is constant but NAME_OF_AN_IMAGE is variable.

Comment: This may fix your problem - `$imagePath = "{0}\{1}" -f PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER, NAME_OF_AN_IMAGE`

Comment: And what about the line in the batch file 'calling' the Powershell script?

Comment: what is the content of temp.txt? please show some examples