# How to evaluate a command as input to another command using Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, command

In Linux I run commands like:

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```

Here, the output of the `llvm-config` command is given as input to the `clang++` command.

What is the equivalent of back ticks (``) in Windows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable

Comment: But is there no other way than assigning to a variable? It feels stupid...

Comment: That's Windows command line for you :)