# How to assign value in batch query

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found a batch query to list the stats of my GPU cards, and I wanted to assign the temperature to a variable.

This is the code for the query:

```
:loop
nvidia-smi --query gpu=index,name,clocks.gr,power.draw,utilization.gpu,fan.speed,temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader
timeout /t 10 >nul

@cls
goto loop
```

How can I assign the temperature.gpu to a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign output of a program to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)

Comment: Not everyone has a NVidia card and it's utilities. Copy-paste the exact output of your command into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output of a command, use a `for /f` loop.

The following code is based on assumptions of how the actual output looks like:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ('"nvidia-smi --query gpu=index,name,clocks.gr,power.draw,utilization.gpu,fan.speed,temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader'") do (
  set index=%%A
  set name=%%B
  set clocks=%%C
  set power=%%D
  set utilization=%%E
  set speed=%%F
  set temperature=%%G
)
```

Once you paste the actual output of your command to your question, I can adapt accordingly.