# Assign output of expression to variable batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running the following command within a batch script:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name ="MyCustomRule"
```

And it gives out either a string "No rules match the specified criteria." or multiple rows.

I would like to be able to assign its output to a variable something like:

```
set a = output(netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name ="MyCustomRule")
```

Such that I can further do `if "%a%" == ""` . Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign output of a program to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like that :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name^="MyCustomRule"') do (
    Set "Output=%%a"
)
Echo Output Result = "%OutPut%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, although I doubt that it will be fun dealing with all the blanks in your string.

Another approach would be using the commands `FIND` or `FINDST` to check your output for the presence of a substring and then to do `IF` statements based on the `%ERRORLEVEL%` generated by these commands.