# Set the output of command to variable in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to find the path of Java in the system using this command.

```
where /r "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java" java.exe
```

Now I want to set the out put of the where command to a variable so that i can use it later in a batch file.

I tried using

```
set JAVA_PATH = where /r "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java" java.exe
```

But that doesn't seems to work.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Use the `for /f` command. Type `for /?` for guidance.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340018/6163527

Answer (score 0):

You could push the results of that command to another batch file and use the `call` function to call those results and then iterate through those results using `FOR`.

The code to output to another batch file would look like this:

```
where /r "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java" java.exe > path.bat
```

**EDIT:** The resulting path.bat file looks like this:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181_32b\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181_32b\jre\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk7\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe
```