# Extract IP-adress from arp -a for mapping map network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

Coming from Linux I'm fighting with a really basic problem with batch scripting on windows. On a LAN a network drive needs to be remapped based on a device MAC address. Finding it's IP can be achieved with this [little script](https://nhutils.ru/blog/en/ip-by-mac/)

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,254) do @start /b ping 192.168.1.%%a -n 2 > nul
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul
arp -a | find /i "01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa"
```

Gives me the following line based on a search for `01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa`

```
192.168.135.3       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

How can I extract/save the IP `192.168.135.3` in a variable called `ASSIGNED_IP` to map the device as drive Y like:

```
net use drive Y /delete
net use Y: \\%ASSIGNED_IP%\files
```

What I've tried without luck: Using a FOR loop for assigning the result as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-using-a-ms-batch-file) further using the substring method as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/228797/395220)

Comment: thanks @LotPings It's failing with `The system cannot find the file 'arp -a | find /i "01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa".`

Comment: `for /f %%a in ('arp -a ^| find /i "01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa" '
) do set "ASSIGNED_IP=%%a"`  but you should 1st initialize the var to naught and afterwards check it is set with an `if defined ASSIGNED_IP ...`.

Comment: perfect this does it! would you post it as an answer that I can accept it?

Comment: That's pretty basic stuff, the for /f parses the output of the command in single quotes (executed by a 2nd cmd.exe) with a default delimiter of space/tab and only token=1 similar to piping to `|awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @LotPings true basic stuff. as said windows is lightyears away for me so this was hard ;)