# batch: change current directory and print it in one line

Tags: batch-file, command-line

how to change the current directory and print it in one line?

I tried `C:\dir1> cd /d D:\dir2 && echo %cd%`

but it prints `C:\dir1`

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) (although it looks very different, it explains *why* your code doesn't work). But Christian's answer is a nice workaround / alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `cd /d D:\dir2 && cd`

According to the windows cmd help page for cd/chdir this will display your current directory:

> Type CD drive: to display the current directory in the specified
> drive.

> Type CD without parameters to display the current drive and
> directory.

Comment: how to save the output to a variable? `cd /d D:\dir2 && set var1=???`

Comment: You should be able to do `cd /d D:\dir2 && for /f %i in ('cd') do set var=%i` if you are using the command prompt directly you have to use %i but if you are doing a batch script it should be %%i. Saving the output to a variable is further answered at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-using-a-ms-batch-file)