# batch - questions about macro "function" (goto, endlocal) from another question's answer

Tags: batch-file, cmd

It concerns the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54425285/14503335

First what I *think* I understand:

`"%$set%"` expands the content as valid command, and because of the newline(s) the "parser" will execute every `%\n%` as a command.

**Questions:**

1. Does `:initMacro` capature all lines or only `set $set=FOR /L %%N in (1 1 2) dO IF %%N==2 ( %\n%` ... `) else setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion^&set argv=?`
2. Why does the script cross-check whether DelayedExpansion is activated? `if "!!"==""`
3. What's the reason for doubled up `endlocal` ?
4. What's the reason for doubled up `(goto) 2>nul` and what does it actually do?
5. Does the script capture `%$set%` and execute the command already at `:initMacro`? (`%%~1`)

   *"To use it, it's not important to understand how the macro itself works."*

Comment: I don't understand the question in `5.`

Comment: Thanks for your time, jeb. 5. `%$set% ipOutput="ipconfig"`; I still don't fully understand whether ipconfig is executed beforehand or not. You have given stuff to read through and an approach to test/understand in a meaningful way, that is very nice.

Comment: I added `5.` to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an important link to understand batch macros.
[ss64: Macro introduction](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html)
[dostips: Macros with parameters appended](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518)

1. **Does `:initMacro` capature all lines or only `set $set=FOR /L %%N in (1 1 2) dO IF %%N==2 ( %\n% ... ) else setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion^&set argv=?`**

- `$set` contains all lines until the first line missing the `%\n%`, because `%\n%` contains a single caret and one line feed character. It joins all lines together

2. **Why does the script cross-check whether DelayedExpansion is activated? `if "!!"==""`**

- There are three occurrences, the first stops the script if delayed expansion is active, because then this macro will be defined incorrectly, the exclamation marks would be removed.
- The first occurrence inside the macro is to decide the path if delayed expansion was enabled or disabled when the macro was called.
- The third occurrence is a gate that ensures, that the `endlocal` is executed only once

3. **What's the reason for doubled up `endlocal` ?**

- Because when the macro starts there are always two `setlocal`, the first in:
   `) else setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion^&set argv=` the next in `set $set=FOR /L %%N in (1 1 2) dO IF %%N==2 ( %\n% setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

4. **What's the reason for doubled up `(goto) 2>nul` and what does it actually do?**

- `(goto) 2>nul` [removes one stacked call level](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6491) but the execution stays inside the current code block. Two of them will remove two call stack levels, in this case they exit the batch file in a clean way.

5. **Does the script capture `%$set%` and execute the command already at `:initMacro`? `(%%~1)`**

- The execution happens in the macro line:
  `for /F "delims=" %%O in ('"%%~2 | findstr /N ^^"') do ( %\n%`

A good way to understand batch macros is to add some debug code.
First begin with examine the macro itself with a simple:

```
set "$set"
```

And then add some debug code inside the macro, like this:

```
set $set=FOR /L %%N in (1 1 2) dO IF %%N==2 ( %\n%
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion                                 %\n%
echo #1 & set "argv" %%\n%
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%1 in ("!argv!") do (            %\n%
        endlocal                                                    %\n%
        endlocal                                                    %\n%
        set "%%~1.Len=0"                                            %\n%
echo #2 & set "%%~1.Len" %%\n%
```