# Import a list of json files to mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, import

I have several `.json` files I want to import to a `mongo` cluster.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file) discussion however it addresses the issue in the context of a single file import.

What I want to achieve is:

**a**) import all files at once

**b**) each file should correspond to the same-name collection, i.e. `foo.json` --> collection `foo`, `bar.json` --> collection `bar` etc

**c**) i want to specify the db name during the import (and if the db does not exist it should be created

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Write a script which loops over all JSON files and import them. If you like to extract any data from the JSON file I recommend the [jq tool](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77676766/mongoimport-json-object-with-1-document-as-an-array-of-documents/77677352#77677352 Databases are created automatically in MongoDB if they don't exist