# use batch scripting and 7-zip to compress files

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a folder composed of files :

"1.txt"
"2.txt"

I need to compress them in a zip thanks to 7-zip via a batch file.
Everything is working well with this script :

```
7za a my_zip.rar 1.txt 2.txt
```

I get a my_zip.rar containing the two files.

The problem is that I need to name the zip file with the date at the time the batch file is executed. So I tried this script :

```
set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%

7za a %year%_%month%.rar 1.txt 2.txt
```

I am getting a folder called "_2" containing a ".rar" containing my 2 files.
I would like to have a "2014_12.rar" file containing my 2 files.

EDIT : Script output :

```
D:\Users>zip.bat
D:\Users>set year=
D:\Users>set month=2/
D:\Users>echo _2/.rar 1.txt 2.txt
 _2/.rar 1.txt 2.txt
D:\Users>7za a _2/.rar 1.txt 2.txt
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning
Updating archive _2/.rar
Compressing  1.txt
Compressing  2.txt
Everything is Ok
```

My zip.bat used :

```
set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
echo %year%_%month%.rar 1.txt 2.txt
7za a %year%_%month%.rar 1.txt 2.txt
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: works fine for me, try maybe to use `"` in the rar file name: `"%year%_%month%.rar"`

Comment: Ok, because with this exe (7za), adding the double quotes changes nothing. Thanks anyway

Comment: I didn't understand. do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes I also tried with 7z.exe, same result : one folder called "_2" containing ".rar" containing my 2 files. It's like the name in my batch file is not well interpreted, but I don't understand why it's working for you.

Comment: can you add the line `echo %year%_%month%.rar 1.txt 2.txt` and add the output to the question?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting a `/` in `%year%` or `%month%` that is being interpreted as a path separator. `echo %year%_%month%` to see what your variables are being assigned.

Comment: year variable is empty and month variable is equal to _2/

Comment: but I don't know how to get year and date, and then remove the backslash in batch scripting.

Comment: Perhaps use `wmic` to get the date.  Win32_Localtime is locale agnostic anyway.  See [Method 2 on this page](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) for a solution.  Or if you simply want to remove a slash from a variable value, [see this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for string manipulations in batch scripting.  (Hint: `%var:/=%` will remove slashes from `%var%` at the time of evaluation.)  I apologize for picking nits, but `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash.  `/` leans forward.  `\ ` leans backward, you see.

Answer (score 0):

You are cutting the year and month parts incorrectly from your `DATE`. As i don't know how the date is formatted in your locale, i just can suggest you `echo %DATE%` on the command line and count the characters correctly, remembering that you have to start with 0. (if you have dd/mm/yyyy, that would be 6,4 and 3,2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stock script I use to get date values. This is built with the preface that your localization is US English; you may need to alter it if that is not your case.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    if "%%B" NEQ "" (
        SET /A FDATE=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A
        SET /A FTIME=%%B*10000+%%C*100+%%E
    )
)

SET DatePartYear=%FDATE:~0,4%
SET DatePartMonth=%FDATE:~4,2%
SET DatePartDay=%FDATE:~6,2%

C:
cd\
cd "Program Files\7-Zip"
7z.exe a D:\%DatePartYear%_%DatePartMonth%.rar D:\1.txt D:\2.txt
pause
```

Comment: the positive thing with `wmic` is, that the output is independent of regional settings. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) for a simpler `wmic` query to get the same result)