# Create Directory using Batch Script with Timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a-%%b)

set mydir="%mydate%-%mytime%"

mkdir %mydir%
```

With above batch script, I can create a directory name like **2015-05-14-11-30 AM**

Now I need to convert the time into 24 format and remove AM/PM

Expected folder name - **2015-05-14-11-30**

How to do it ?

Comment: I think you should use a solution, that is does not depend on local settings. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) for an example.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389 - you'll find more than enough ways to create time stamps with minimum prerequisites

Comment: I think the problem about local settings is or isn't a problem depending on your own requirements. Maybe for @ChamingaD is OK `date` and `time`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use the `%TIME%` pseudo-variable.

This is an example:

```
@echo off

For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/:." %%a in ("%TIME%") do (
    SET HH24=%%a
    SET MI=%%b
    SET SS=%%c
    SET FF=%%d
)

For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/,." %%a in ("%SS%") do (
    SET JUST_SS=%%a
)

echo HH24=%HH24%
echo MI=%MI%
echo SS=%SS%
echo FF=%FF%
echo JUST_SS=%JUST_SS%

echo mytime=%HH24%-%MI%-%JUST_SS%
```

Well, I realized HH24 has an empty space if the hour is less than 10, so here you have another solution, using `%time`:

```
SET HH=%time:~0,2%
if "%HH:~0,1%" == " " SET HH=0%HH:~1,1%
    echo HH=%HH%

SET MI=%time:~3,2%
if "%MI:~0,1%" == " " SET MI=0%MI:~1,1%
    echo MI=%MI%

SET SS=%time:~6,2%
if "%SS:~0,1%" == " " SET SS=0%SS:~1,1%
    echo SS=%SS%
```

**Following the advice pointed out by @Stephan (`TIME` variable is dependent on region settings), we can use this approach:**

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set datetime=%%a

set "YYYY=%datetime:~0,4%"
set "MM=%datetime:~4,2%"
set "DD=%datetime:~6,2%"
set "HH=%datetime:~8,2%"
set "MI=%datetime:~10,2%"
set "SS=%datetime:~12,2%"

set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%-%HH%-%MI%-%SS%
echo fullstamp=%fullstamp%
```

Comment: `TIME` variable is dependent on time /region settings...Check my comment under the question

Comment: The last script uses `localdatetime`.

Answer (score 1):

lets make it simple & short

```
 @echo off

 set hh=%time:~-11,2%
 set /a hh=%hh%+100
 set hh=%hh:~1%
 Set mydir=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%hh%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
 mkdir %mydir%
```

Comment: `TIME` variable is dependent on time /region settings...Check my comment under the question

Comment: @npocmaka this script seems to be working and simple. can you explain me the issue?

Comment: `echo %date%` on my computer returns `14.May.2015` .I have suspicious that your solution will not work on my machine :)

Comment: For that reason, another option is to use `localdatetime` (see the last script in my answer)