# mysqldump with date and time in backup file name on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, filenames, mysql

I am unix man, and I really don't like work on windows. I am asking You for help.

I am trying to make regular backups of mysql database in microsoft windows cmd. Here is my current script for that:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -ppass stp > V:\backup_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%.sql
```

I would like to file name have structure like that:

```
backup_3.2.2.6__2015-06-02_10:25:35.sql
```

where is:

```
name__currentDate_currentTime.sql
```

So I just need to add current time to file name.

Please help

Comment: Filenames on windows cannot contain ':'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is working solution:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -ppass stp > V:\backup_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql
```

Where "pass" is Your password for root user

Comment: I have found this approach to work in Windows 7. A nice one line solution. It also works with producing a zipped file. Really good solution.

Comment: It works, but also depends on the set date format. Would you care to explain your solution and how would you set the time format to hh:MM:ss instead of hh-MM-SS

Answer (score 4):

You can not have `:` as a part of the file name on Windows.
Try the following batch file, it will create file with the name in the format such as: `backup_3.2.2.6__2015-06-02_17-50-44.sql`:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
set datetime=%datetime:~0,4%-%datetime:~4,2%-%datetime:~6,2%_%datetime:~8,2%-%datetime:~10,2%-%datetime:~12,2%
"C:\xampp\mysql\mysqldump.exe" -hlocalhost -uroot -ppass svp > "V:\backup_3.2.2.6__%datetime%.sql"
```

I have used wmic example from the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/4947851

Comment: I don't understand Your code. Why to use for loop to get current date and time?

Comment: Code in `for` loop will create string which is independent of windows locale settings. `%date%` on its own will give different results on different locale settings. As I don't know your locale this was a suggestion how to make it work on any windows machine. To run this code, save it as `something.bat` and run it from command line. However, if you know `%date%` format will always be same, you can easily format string based on that.