# CMD/BATCH - Had to run batch script 3 times to get full result

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
REM returns current date and time as var datestamp in YYYYMMDD_hhmm format
REM         current date as variable date in YYYYMMDD format
REM         current time as variable time in hhmm format
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('DATE /T') do set date=%%c%%a%%b
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('TIME /T') do set hr=%%a
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('TIME /T') do set mi=%%b
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=: " %%a in ('TIME /T') do set ampm=%%c
set time=%hr%%mi%

IF %ampm% EQU PM ( 
    REM in case of 12 PM we don't need to perform any actions
    IF %hr% EQU 12 GOTO end
    REM in case of another hour 1-11 PM we need to reformat it to 24-hour format by adding 12 hours
    set /A hour=1%hr%+12-100
    set time=%hour%%mi%
) ELSE (
    REM only in case of 12 AM we need to reformat it to 24-hour format by extracting 12 hours (00 hours)
    IF %hr% EQU 12 (
        set /A temp=1%hr%-12-100
        set hour=0%temp%
        set time=%hour%%mi%
    )
)
GOTO end
:end
set datestamp=%date%_%time%
```

This is just the script which generates date-time in 24-hour format (maybe here is some better way to do that). However it does not work. I had to run it 3 times before it shows complete results:

```
D:\utils\scripts>getDateStamp.cmd & echo %datestamp%
%datestamp%

D:\utils\scripts>getDateStamp.cmd & echo %datestamp%
20150609_55

D:\utils\scripts>getDateStamp.cmd & echo %datestamp%
20150609_1855
```

What might be the problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: you fell into the famous [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) is a nice and easy way to get a good formatted date-time string, 24h format and independent of locale settings. Easy to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Also worth noting that `%date%` and `%time%` are already system variables, and you should change your variable names to something else.

Comment: @SomethingDark, thanks, I've already figured it out.

Comment: Please post your answer so that anyone searching for a similar problem will benefit from your answer.