# Batch Script that saves log files

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging

I am currently using a program called `USBDeviewer` for auditing purposes. Basically what it does is it gets a list of USB devices that were used on a particular PC. The program can create a log file but you have to do it manually. The keyboard command to save a log file is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all devices and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save. After you select save you are prompted to enter a filename and location to save it.

I need a batch script that will automatically run this program and save the information on the log file to a folder automatically without any human intervention such as typing in the name (it needs a different name every time, perhaps  the filename can include a different date every time).

This is a simple script but I am not familiar with batch scripting so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Via its command line `usbdeview.exe /stext c:\temp\thefile.txt`

Comment: See this for date/time file name: [Batch command date and time in file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

**[Save Command-Line Options for usbdeview.exe](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)**

**/stext Filename** : Save the list of all USB devices into a regular text file.

```
@echo off
set Log=c:\temp\logfile.txt
usbdeview.exe /stext %Log%
```