# "move/ren" gives syntax error, I can't figure solution

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to rename some folders with a batch-file, but everything I try gives me syntax errors.  Here is what I have currently:

```
for /d %%a in (%cd%\*.*) do call :moveandrename %%~nxa %%a
.
.
.
:moveandrename
if exist %2\%1.pdf if exist %2\%1.xml move "%2" "%~dp0\export\_verarbeitet"
ren "%~dp0\export\_verarbeitet\%1" "%1_verarbeitet_%date%_%time%"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: are there spaces in the paths?

Comment: Try quoting your filenames and use `~` to strip quotes if passed.  `if exist "%~2\%~1.pdf" if exist "%~2\%~1.xml"`

Comment: No spaces in Paths...

Comment: Ampersands in paths?

Comment: What kind of syntax errors do you get? Remeber that you must exit your sub (movedandrename) with a goto :eof command. Also before the moveandrename-lable you must add a goto :eof otherwise you end up in this section once the for-loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug...

adding "%time" to foldername caused syntax error, this is how it works

```
mkdir export\1
mkdir export\_verarbeitet
rem.>export\1\1.pdf
rem.>export\1\1.xml
for /d %%a in (%~dp0export\*.*) do call :moveandrename %%~nxa %%a
goto :eof
:moveandrename
if exist "%~2\%~1.pdf" if exist "%~2\%~1.xml" move "%2" "%~dp0export\_verarbeitet\"
ren "%~dp0export\_verarbeitet\%1" "%1_verarbeitet_%date%"
pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: `%date%` and `%time%` may contain illegal characters for filenames and depend on locale settings. Better use a [global solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)