# Batch Script: Search thru multiple files for part of an IP address and log it

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple TraceRT log files containing 30 hops.  I'm only looking for similar IP (ex. 192.168.1) and would like to log it on one file with:
1) Successful: %IP% found in %Filename%
2) Fail: Specified IP not found in %Filename%

I'm trying to use:

```
rem************************************************************
:START

@ ECHO OFF

rem US date
set YEAR=%DATE:~10,4%
set MONTH=%DATE:~4,2%
set DAY=%DATE:~7,2%

rem US hour
set HOUR=%TIME:~0,2%
set MIN=%TIME:~3,2%
set SEC=%TIME:~6,2%
set HUNDREDS=%TIME:~9,2%
set HOURMIN=%HOUR%%MIN%

rem Make sure that hour has two digits
IF %HOUR% GEQ 10 goto twoh
set HOUR1=%TIME:~1,1%
set TWOHOUR=0%HOUR1%
goto fulltid

:twoh
set TWOHOUR=%HOUR%

:fulltid
set FULLTIME=%TWOHOUR%'%MIN%'%SEC%'%HUNDREDS%
set FTIME=%TWOHOUR%:%MIN%:%SEC%


@echo off & setLocal EnableDELAYedeXpansion
findstr /m "192.168.1" *.txt > FILENAME 
echo on
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (*.txt ^| find "192.168.1") do (
IF %%a neq %%b (
echo Suscessful: %%a  %FILENAME%  >> Log%YEAR%%MONTH%%DAY%.txt
) ELSE (
echo Fail: Specified IP not found in %FILENAME% >> Log%YEAR%%MONTH%%DAY%.txt
)
)

goto START

rem************************************************************
```

Comment: There is no `%%b`, as you have only one token: `*`

Comment: instead of messing with local date/time formats, I strongly recommend an locale independent approach [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have specified an invalid pipe `| find`. You cannot pipe (a) text file(s) into a command.
   Either provide the file(s) as argument(s) to `find`, or use redirection (this works for a single file only but not for multiple ones nor `*`/`?` patterns though).
2. You are using `for /f` not correctly.
   It looks as if you wanted to parse the output of `find`. To accomplish that, but you *must* enclose the command within single-quotes `'`. Type `for /?` and see the help text for more details.

The following line of code should work:

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find "192.168.1" *.txt') do (
```

---

To get current date and time, I strongly recommend to read variables `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` *once only* and within a *single line*! Otherwise you might run into problems, especially concerning the fractional seconds, which might not be equal between consecutive expansions.

To ensure `%HOUR%` to have two digits, you simply need to use `set HOUR=0%HOUR%` then `set HOUR=%HOUR:~-2%`.

Since a one-digit `%HOUR%` is prefixed by a space here, you can have it even simpler (thanks for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216178/batch-script-search-thru-multiple-files-for-part-of-an-ip-address-and-log-it/32216846#comment52323026_32216846), @Stephan!) by just replacing the space by a zero: `set HOUR=%HOUR: =0%`.

Comment: here is an easier "two digit hour trick": `set "hour=%hour: =0%"` (replace the space with a zero)