# Batch set date format YYMMDD

Tags: date, batch-file

Does anyone know how to set YYMMDD (not 4xYYYY) as a date format in batch? All i found was yyyymmdd, but I just need the two last numbers in the year. So instead of 2015, I need 15 as the output.

I've got this so far;

```
set mydate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
echo %mydate%
```

This gives me todays date in this format; `20151214`, which isn't what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%date:~6,4%` means "from the DATE variable take a substring starting with the 7th char (it starts with ZERO for the first char, so `6` means the seventh char) with length=4. Once you understand that, it's easy: `%date:~8,2%`

NOTE: this method depends on individual computersettings and therefore doesn't work correct on every Computer.
I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082). To extract 'YYMMDD' only, Change the last line there to: `set mydate=%datetime:~2,6%`

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! And thank you for the explanation as well. Did not know that was the way it worked.

Comment: It's described in detail when you do a `set /?` on the command prompt (a lot to read, but worth the time)

Answer (score 2):

```
set mydate=%date:~8,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
echo %mydate%
```