# use variable in command line batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, winscp

I use the following command in a batch file:

```
winscp sitename /command "get /filename.160313.tgz q:\localfolder\"
```

which downloads the file using winscp program.

What I'd like to do is have "160313" be automatically generated based on today's date.

How would I replace `160313` with such variable?

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Comment: You'd need to show us the format in which your machine displays the variable `%date%`.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

echo %YY%%MM%%DD%

winscp sitename /command "get /filename.%YY%%MM%%DD%.tgz q:\localfolder\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 C:\Users\User>echo %date:/= %
 Sun 13 03 2016
```

or for no spaces

```
set var=%date:/=%
```

Else you can use substring extraction

```
set var=%date:~-4%
```

for the year. See `set /?`.

Comment: I showed you how to get the year. Use generalisation to solve the rest of the problem. And your quickness of reply means you didn't read help.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP has its own [syntax for generating timestamped names](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
WinSCP.com /command ... "get /filename.%%TIMESTAMP#YYMMDD%%.tgz q:\localfolder\"
```

See also [Formatting timestamp in batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_formatting_timestamp_batch_file).