# how to find specific files in a folder using windows batch programming

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path

i need to write a bat file which can give me the last names of files in a network folder.The names has the specific pattern.simmilar to this pattern.

```
Deepak.DEMO.yyyymmdd
mcapatna.POWERHOUSE.yyyymmdd
```

where Deepak.DEMO & mcapatna.POWERHOUSE are fixed but yyyymmdd is variable depends on the year month & date.

1. I have to find this `yyyymmdd`  using batch programming &
2. if possible than compare it with current date.if it is today date then proceed further otherwise move these file to different folder.
   I tried a lot but i am unable to do it.could someone please help me.

Comment: Please put the code you have tried so far with your question... For getting the files with "yyyymmdd" given, you can use the `dir /b *.<yyyymmdd>` command. Check the `/b` switch at `dir /?`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%i in (Deepak.DEMO.* mcapatna.POWERHOUSE.*) do echo %%~xi
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) for a possible solution to get the date in the same format. Comparing for equality should be trivial.