# get current date in yyyyMMdd format in spring batch configuration XML

Tags: spring

I have spring batch configuration for spring outbound sftp which has

```
<property name="remoteDirectory" value="/SFTP/Books_File_20160629"></property>
```

I want _20160629 to be today's date in same yyyymmdd format rather than hard coding.

Please tell me is there any way for that ?

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)

Comment: This is very confusing. I actually want java spring batch XML way to put today's date in yyyMMdd format but only using XML, don't want to make any java class         . e.g.                                                                   <bean id="fastDateFormat" class="org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyy/MM/dd"/>
</bean>

<bean id="currentDate" class="java.util.Date" factory-bean="fastDateFormat" factory-method="format">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.Date"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

```
<property name="resources" value="/SFTP/Books_File_*#{currentDate}"/>
```

Below beans should be added in your context.xml

```
<bean id="fastDateFormat" class="org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat"
    factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyyMMdd" />
</bean>

<bean id="currentDate" class="java.util.Date" factory-bean="fastDateFormat"
    factory-method="format">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.Date" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: was about to suggest that :) would be better if you made an example using classic singleton, instead of referring to third party libraries

Comment: Yes it would be better. But as it is from apache commons library i think better to use existing implementation.

Comment: @Jay Thank you! :)

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: Is there a way to implement this solution with fastDateFormat, except getting the previous business day instead of currentDate?