# How to create a batch file, which will make a folder with date and time as folder name in each 4 hrs

Tags: batch-file

How to create a batch file, which will make a folder with date and time as folder name in each 1 hrs

I have a folder name in c drive 'test', my instrument will generate a txt file in the same folder. data will update and accumulate in the txt file in each 2 min.

I want to copy the same txt file from the location and paste in another location in every 1 Hr.

each time copying I want to create a new folder with name as current date and current time.

Comment: Create a batch file containing [MD](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) [TIME](http://ss64.com/nt/time.html) and set it as a scheduled task.

Comment: please check, if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) may help you.

Comment: OK. But how to copy paste the txt files from c:\test\ to the new generated folder.  can you please give me the commands

Comment: `copy`, `xcopy`, `robocopy`. [here](http://ss64.com/nt/) you can find a list of all available commands and a description of each..

Comment: Stephan, actually I used all, but how to copy the file into the newly created folder which I created using command

Answer (score 3):

the trick is: don't create your folder with something like `md %time%` (wouldn't work anyway), but create a variable and use that for `md` AND `copy`:

```
@echo off
REM change to the destination folder:
cd /D c:\destination
REM generate datetime-string:
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
REM format to the desired format (example):
set string=%datetime:~0,12%
REM create a subfolder:
md %string%
REM xopy the file:
copy "c:\test\myfile.txt" "c:\destination\%string%\"
```

Instead of creating a new folder with a single file inside, I would just rename the textfiles to include the date-time-string:
forget the `md` command and replace the `copy` line with:
`copy "c:\test\myfile.txt" "c:\destination\%string%-myfile.txt"`

To execute it regularily, I recommend using a scheduled task.

Comment: thank you Stephan , really works.......:)