# creating a folder name with a batch file

Tags: datetime, batch-file, time, directory

I am trying to create a folder using batch file. The folder name should be in a format - yyyymmdd-hhmm .I got started with the below code but I get yyyymmdd- as one folder and hhmm as another folder. But when I tried it after 13.00 hrs I get yyyymmdd-hhmm format. Why is there a different behaviour during 9:45 in the morning. I don't know. Any help appreciated.

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
mkdir %mydate%-%mytime%
```

I get 1 folder -> 20160810- and another folder -> 945.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I get 1 folder -> 20160810- and another folder -> 945."

That's because of the space, so `mkdir` sees two parameters and so creates two folders.

Either put qoutes around the new foldername

```
mkdir "%mydate%-%mytime%"`
```

or (maybe better) replace the space with a zero:

```
mkdir %mydate%-%mytime: =0%
```

putting qoutes around anyway doesn't harm:

```
mkdir "%mydate%-%mytime: =0%"
```

(btw: there is a way to [get a date-time-string independent of local settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082))

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But instead of the folder name ->20160810-945 ,can I get like -> 20160810-0945

Comment: this should do. If not, please let me know your output of `echo -%time%-` (before 10:00 am please)

Comment: OK I will test it before 10.00 am. by the way when I tried mkdir "%mydate%-%mytime: =0%" it did not create a folder, it create a file with name yyyymmdd-

Comment: wait - `mkdir` is creating a *file*?? There is something fundametaly wrong. Do you happen to have a `mkdir.bat`?