# Batch: search for files with certain extension, owner, fullpath and last write access and output in CSV

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, file-properties

I'm trying to create a CSV with fullpath\filename, file owner and last write access (modification date) of all txt and html files from all hard drives of a data server.

Here's what I got so far:

```
set pgm=%~n0
set log=%~dpn0.log
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
set csv=%host%.csv
set dir=D:\BME

if not exist "%csv%" type nul>"%csv%"
    for /f "delims=;" %%a in ('dir /b/s %dir%\*.txt, %dir%\*.html') do (
    >>%csv% echo "%%a"
)
```

That outputs the path + filename of all found txt and html files of a certain folder in a CSV. I tried this command to get the hard drives:

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get caption
```

But I can't get my head around how to store that in a variable or file and loop through it and also retrieve the owner and last modification date and put it into a new column of the csv file.

Comment: How did you capture the output of the `dir` command line? perhaps the same method works for `wmic` either... by the way, `wmic` can also be used to retrieve file information -- see `wmic DataFile /?`...

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I can't get my head around how to store that in a variable

Use the following batch file.

**GetDrives.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem skip=1 to remove the header
rem findstr to remove blank lines
for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=3 get caption ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  set _drive=%%d
  echo !_drive!
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Be careful when using `drivetype=3` as I have a removable drive of type `3`. In the below output `C:` is a fixed hard disk and `F:` is a removable external USB drive.
- Replace `echo !_drive!` as appropriate with a modified version of your existing code.

**Example Output:**

```
F:\test>GetDrives
C:
F:

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Answer (score 1):

[DavidPostill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill) answered [how-to store `wmic logicaldisk …` output in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39036677/3439404);

- to retrieve file last modification date: use `echo "%%a","%%~ta"` in your script using [`%~t` Parameter Extension](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html);
- to retrieve file owner: `echo "%%a","%%~ta","!_owner!"` where `_owner` variable comes from `getRealOwner` subroutine based on modified [schletti2000's answer *Get ownership information from command line by using `wmic`*](https://superuser.com/a/1103541/376602).

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "pgm=%~n0"
set "log=%~dpn0.log"
set "host=%COMPUTERNAME%"
set "csv=%host%.csv"
set "dir=D:\BME"
set "dirmask=%dir%\*.txt, %dir%\*.html"

rem if not exist "%csv%" type nul>"%csv%"
>"%csv%" (
    for /f "delims=;" %%a in ('dir /b/s %dirmask% 2^>NUL') do (
          set "_fFullPath=%%~a"
          set "_fLastWrite=%%~ta"
          set "_fOwner="
          call :getRealOwner
          SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo "!_fFullPath!","!_fOwner!","!_fLastWrite!"
          ENDLOCAL
      ) 
    )
)
type "%csv%"
goto :continue

:getRealOwner
SET "ESCAPED=%_fFullPath:\=\\%"

SET "UNDELIMITED="
for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%g in ('
  wmic path Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting where Path^="%ESCAPED%" ^
    ASSOC /RESULTROLE:Owner /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_LogicalFileOwner ^
          /RESULTCLASS:Win32_SID 2^>NUL
  ') do (
      SET "UNDELIMITED=%%g"
      call :process_wmioutput
)
if NOT defined UNDELIMITED set "_fOwner=???"
exit /B

:process_wmioutput
SET "DELIMITED=%UNDELIMITED:  =•%"
FOR /F "delims=• tokens=10,12" %%G in ("%DELIMITED%") DO set "_fOwner=%%H\%%G"
exit /B

:continue
```

I used next settings to demonstrate various output:

```
set "dir=D:"      
set "dirmask=%dir%\loc*.vbs %dir%\bcd*.log %dir%\act*.xsl %dir%\diag*.xml %dir%\chec*.csv"
```

**Output** - non-privileged `cmd` window:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\39034430.bat
"D:\odds and ends\tempx\links\testDJ\LocUsers.vbs","mypc\user","25.12.2014 00:13"
"D:\tempWin\ActivityLog.xsl","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","24.02.2016 13:12"
"D:\tempWin\CompatTelemetryLogs\diagerr.xml","???","12.08.2015 03:17"
"D:\tempWin\CompatTelemetryLogs\diagwrn.xml","???","12.08.2015 03:17"
"D:\test\check_acl.csv","BUILTIN\Administrators","06.03.2016 14:28"
```

**Output** - privileged (run as administrator) `cmd` window:

```
=ADMIN=> D:\bat\SO\39034430.bat
"D:\odds and ends\tempx\links\testDJ\LocUsers.vbs","mypc\user","25.12.2014 00:13"
"D:\tempWin\ActivityLog.xsl","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","24.02.2016 13:12"
"D:\tempWin\CompatTelemetryLogs\diagerr.xml","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","12.08.2015 03:17"
"D:\tempWin\CompatTelemetryLogs\diagwrn.xml","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","12.08.2015 03:17"
"D:\test\check_acl.csv","BUILTIN\Administrators","06.03.2016 14:28"
```