# Batch scripting task of appending timpestamp to a filename in the format 'filename_timestamp.ext'

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I tried using this code:

```
SET Tmstp=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
FOR %%V IN (%1) DO copy %%V %%V_%Tmstp%.bat && move %%V_%Tmstp% %Target%
echo %0
```

but it returns the filename in the format `filename.bat_timestamp`, but I need it as `filename_timestamp.bat`.

Any help will be great.

Comment: for date-time-stamp, I recommend a) another format: `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` because it's easily sortable and b) a [locale independent solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need modifiers (described in `for /?`. These modifiers allow you to access each element of a file name (drive, path, name, extension and some other properties) separately:

```
... DO copy "%%V" "%%~nV_%Tmstp%%%~xV" && move "%%~nV_%Tmstp%%%~xV" "%Target%"
```

or if you need the full path:

```
... DO copy "%%~fV" "%%~dpnV_%Tmstp%%%~xV" && move "%%~dpnV_%Tmstp%%%~xV" "%Target%"
```

Comment: Hey Stephan. Thank you. Got the desired output. Also changed the timestamp format. Cheers!