# How to create new folders with today's date(No Separators)

Tags: date, cmd, directory

I am using md "%date%".
This makes a folder named 24-11-2016, but i don't want the separator '-'.
It should name the folder as 24112016.

Comment: What language you are talking about?

Comment: basic cmd command

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Batch command date and time in file name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7727114/5047996)

Answer (score -1):

**I found the answer :**

%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~6,4%

~0 Signifies that day should start at 0th place and the 2 following the ',' signifies that it should take two places.
Same way ~3 signifies that month start at 3rd place and the 2 following that signifies that it should take two places
and ~6 signifies that year should start at 6th place and the 4 following signifies that it should take four places

The Output comes as : 24112016, if you want 24-11-2016 then simply write %date%.

Comment: This is only an answer if the machine has regional settings for the date format to be DD-MM-YYYY. Have a look at `wmic os get LocalDateTime` which always outputs the same format.