# Rename file having & in file name with today's date

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I want to rename an MS-word file `CEEMEA & LATAM.Docx` into `CEEMEA & LATAM 113018.Docx` which includes today's date using `cmd`.

Both `.Docx` and `.Bat` files are in same folder. I start with following command and getting "system cannot find the path specificied".

```
ren "CEEMEA & LATAM.Docx" "CEEMEA & LATAM %date%.Docx"
```

Comment: What do you mean by that it doesn't seem to be working? What result do you expect to get and what result are you getting/not getting? Is there an error message?

Comment: `system cannot find the path specificied` error but file is there with correct name

Comment: Run `cd <path-to-the-file>` and try your `ren` again from that directory. Or you could include the full path directly, like `ren "C:\Users\MyUser\CEEMEA & LATAM.docx" "C:\Users\MyUser\CEEMEA & LATAM %date%.docx"`

Comment: see [here how to get a valid date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name/18024049#18024049) for your filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `date` variable in batch file contains:

- The first three letters of the day today (but in some systems this does not exist).
- The date today (formats are different per system) [**numbers are usually seperated by `/` symbol which is interpreted as directory separator**].

This way creates a datestamp with **`mmddyy`** format **IN CMD**:

```bat
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %A in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%A"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
rem M=month D=day Y=Year
set datestamp=%MM%%DD%%YY%
rem Change datestamp variable as you want.
ren "CEEMEA & LATAM.Docx" "CEEMEA & LATAM %datestamp%.Docx"
```

*Note: The above code is only for cmd. If you want it for a batch file **double the percent signs (%) of the loop variables** (`%A` should become `%%A` in both two cases)*.