# How to change multiple file names according to there names along with date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 7 files. in bat file I want to check name of files  and then raname with current date.  just like an `if`/`else` condition

**Example**

1. `abc.txt` rename to `xyz20190715_1.txt` *(xyzyyyymmdd_1.txt)*
2. `pqr.txt` rename to `def20190715_1.txt` *(defyyyymmdd_1.txt)*

I'm new to batch files and tried this:

```
 for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename
 "abc.txt" %%e-%%f-%%g.dat
```

**Expected output**

1. `abc.txt` rename to `xyz20190715_1.txt`
2. `pqr.txt` rename to `def20190715_1.txt`

Comment: where do `xyz` and `def` come from?

Comment: Since we can't see what the code did on your system, you need to tell us. You should also specify the date-format you are using by showing a sample of the value of `%date%`.

Comment: xyz and def  is sample  name that should include at start of file name

Comment: I understood, what it does, but where does it come from?

Comment: it need to be harcoded in batch file

Comment: (*sigh*) How to know that `abc` should be translated to `xyz` while `pqr` should become `def` - if you have a lot of files, we will have to know how that substituion should work.

Comment: Suppose I have total 7 files with different name. Have to loop through all files and according to that file names change there names1) contract.txt to DNSMyyyymmdd_x.DAT
2) security.dat to NSMyyyymmdd_x.DAT
3) Participant.txt to PMyyyymmdd_x.DAT
4) SCRIP_master.txt to BSMyyyymmdd_x.DAT
5) DPRxxxx to BSE_YearlyHLyyyymmdd_x.DAT
6) fo_participant.txt  DPMyyyymmdd_x.DAT
7) spd_ contract.txt to SCMyyyymmdd_x.DAT

Comment: have only 7 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"to loop through files" is something like

```
for %%I in (*.txt) do echo %%I
```

that's why I asked how to know the substitutions.

As there seems to be no rule, you have to rename each file individually (no big harm with only 7 files, but with a hundred ore more it would drive you crazy). I also used a differnt way to get the date string (independent of locale settings):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set "datetime=%%I"
set "datetime=%datetime:~0,8%"

ren "contract.txt" "DNSM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "security.DAT"" "NSM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "Participant.txt" "PM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "SCRIP_master.txt" "BSM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "DPRxxxx" "BSE_YearlyHL%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "fo_participant.txt" "DPM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "spd_ contract.txt" "SCM%datetime%_x.DAT"
```

Comment: @PrakashMhasavekar, the code above uses `_x.DAT`, as in your comment. If you wanted `_1.txt` as in your question, please adjust the `7` lines as necessary.

Comment: how to get next date in same format. I'm trying to add with +1 but it is not working

Comment: Doable in pure batch, but I suggest to take the help of some other language (like Powershell) to keep your sanity intact. There are [a lot of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+tomorrows+date) - take your choice.

Comment: Problem is my one file comes with next day's date DPR_ddmmyy format and second with current date script_ddmmyy. I managed to find and rename Script_ddmmyy which comes with current date. Now one file remaining with tommorrows date...

Comment: I don't really understand - and code is incredibly hard to read in comments. Please ask a new question instead (as actually it's another problem).

Comment: Solved Sir...  using (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString('ddMMyy')"`) I got next date.. Thank you for your support @Stephan Sir

Comment: You're welcome. Btw: don't mess with the system variable `%date%` - choose another name (like `%tomorrow%`)

Comment: Yes sir. I added variable as  %nextDate%.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is to get the actual date, then for today's date it's better to do the following:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year /value') do >nul set "%%a"
    set Month=00%Month%
    set Month=%Month:~-2%
    set Day=00%Day%
    set Day=%Day:~-2%
set today=%Year%%Month%%Day%
```

Otherwise you need to ask a real question, which starts with "how do I"

Comment: there is an [even simpler method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) for the desired format.

Comment: date time format is yyyymmdd need in filename but with some hardcoded text at starting of name ie. stackoverflow20190715.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq" %%B in (`"powershell (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"`) do set "datetime=%%B


echo Today's Date %datetime%
ren "contract.txt" "DNSM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "security.DAT"" "NSM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "Participant.txt" "PM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "SCRIP_master.txt" "BSM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "DPRxxxx" "BSE_YearlyHL%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "fo_participant.txt" "DPM%datetime%_x.DAT"
ren "spd_ contract.txt" "SCM%datetime%_x.DAT"

pause
exit
```