# how can I copy a folder fully to another folder and change is is name by adding date

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a batch file that will create a back-up folder of my game every time I close it but when i try it it just say that my destination name is invalid
here's what I tried:

```
set name='\save\world|%date%-%time%'
echo R | xcopy world %name% /E/H
pause
```

Comment: a) single quotes do nothing special in batch - they are just like any character. b) `|` isn't a valid character for a file name. c) your `date` and `time` variables probably also contain characters that are not valid in file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "for" to parse the tokens in a string, command, or directory listing.  the "for" command winds up doing much of the heavy lifting in batch files.

```
for /f "Tokens=1-4 Delims=:. " %%i in ("%time%") do set tm=%%i.%%j.%%k.%%l
for /f "Tokens=1-4 Delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do set dt=%%l.%%j.%%k
set bkupname=\temp\save\world-%dt%.%tm%\
xcopy world %bkupname% /E /H
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks like Stephan said

> a) single quotes do nothing special in batch - they are just like any character. b) | isn't a valid character for a file name. c) your date and time variables probably also contain characters that are not valid in file names.

so here's what I did and it works so thanks

```
set name="world %date:~0,2% %date:~3,2% %date:~8,2% %time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%"
echo R | xcopy world .\save\worldtemp /E/H
move .\save\worldtemp .\save\%name%
pause
```

Comment: you should enclose path/file names in double-quotes to correctly process spaces: `move ".\save\worldtemp" ".\save\%name%"`

Comment: and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) for a better method to get the date/time string.