# Windows Batch rename files with its Created Datetime with second

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I found the below code which works in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```
FOR /R "C:\Folder" %Z IN (*.tif) DO @( FOR /F "Tokens=1-6 delims=:-\/. " %A IN ("%~tZ") DO @( ren "%~dpnxZ" "%~A_%~B%~C_%~D%~E_%~nZ%~xZ") )
```

However, I have got two problems.

1. I need to run it in [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)
2. I cannot get seconds or even milliseconds as filename

Answer (score 0):

Inside a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) the **`%`** characters require doubling:

```bat
@For /R "C:\Folder" %%G In (*.tif)Do @For /F "Tokens=1-5Delims=:-\/. " %%H In ("%%~tG")Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~H_%%~I%%~J_%%~K%%~L_%%~nxG"
```

Although, in a batch file, I'd suggest that you do not use a single line, *(limiting line lengths within `80` characters to match the default cmd.exe window width and to assist reading)*:

```bat
@For /R "C:\Folder" %%G In (*.tif)Do @For /F "Tokens=1-5Delims=:-\/. " %%H In (
    "%%~tG")Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~H_%%~I%%~J_%%~K%%~L_%%~nxG"
```

BTW, your initial [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) example could have looked more like this:

```bat
For /R "C:\Folder" %G In (*.tif)Do @For /F "Tokens=1-5Delims=:-\/. " %H In ("%~tG")Do @Ren "%G" "%~H_%~I%~J_%~K%~L_%~nxG"
```

*You had some unnecessary parentheses and an unused token and could have merged the name and extension into a single modifier instead of two. You could also have removed the unnecessary expansion and modifiers from the filename to be renamed.*

---

**[Edit /]**
BTW, you'll note that I didn't answer your second question, because the `%~t` modifier doesn't output seconds and milliseconds, *(you could therefore probably remove the `.` delimiter)*, so you cannot retrieve it from that code. You would therefore need to use an alternative method, and this site does not provide a free code writing service, so you'd need to post a new question once you have that code. Also problems/issues should be limited to only one per post.

Comment: @user2306468: you can find a method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) (replace `LastModified` with `CreationDate`)

Comment: But @user2306468, please read [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/937380) and answers first.

Answer (score 0):

I have used powershell to rename the file at the end

```
dir $args[0] | foreach {
  $newname = "$($_.CreationTime.toString('yyyyMMdd-HHmmssfff'))-$($_.Name)"
  if (test-path $newname) {
    "Cannot rename $_"
  } else {
    ren $_ $newname 
  }
}
```