# How to redirect output new file anytime

Tags: batch-file

i have a question
I get this script

```
for /f "tokens=* " %%d in ('tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8') do (
echo %%d
) >>test.txt
```

but I would like condition as below
1. save new file when i do run this script anytime 
example

```
run 1 > create new file1
run 2 > create new file2
run 3 > create new file3

ever
```

2. the script  continues run 1 minute
3. if i need to file name  is date time is there anyways

thank for answer

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) answer your question?

Comment: Add to your question: What version of Windows.

Comment: why don't just use `tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8>FILE`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment posted above by Stephan you can do something like that :

(independent of locale settings)

```bat
@echo off
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime
echo %filename%.txt
( @for /f "tokens=* " %%d in ('tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8') do echo %%d )>%filename%.txt
If Exist %filename%.txt Start "" %filename%.txt
pause
Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "filename=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
exit /b
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Comment: if  run finished  don't show output  is there anyway.

Comment: @assb: add a `cd /d "%~dp0"` as second line (right after `@echo off`)