# WMIC lastmodified include in for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, wmic, last-modified

I am trying to get the lastmodified date of files which have almost the samename (CompactReg00 in common).

I want this date to be safe to different date settings so I was thinking to use wmic command.
The command work well if I use it like that :

```
set filename=CompactReg00_20200504T112430Z
for /f %%p in ('wmic  DataFile where "name='C:\\Temp\\Alarm\\Archive\\20200508\\sDiag\\%filename%'" get lastmodified   ^| find "+" ') do set "val=%%p"
echo %val%
```

but when I want to include it to another for loop to get lastmodied date of all "CompactReg00" files I cannot get the %val% value

here is my script:

```
for /R %%a IN (*CompactReg00*) DO (
        echo %%~na
        for /f %%p in ('wmic  DataFile where "name='C:\\Temp\\Alarm\\Archive\\20200508\\sDiag\\%%~na'" get lastmodified   ^| find "+" ') do set "val=%%p"
        echo %val%
        echo %%~na_%val%
        )
```

Can you help me to correct it or find another way to get this lastmodified date always yyyymmdd

Comment: a [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) issue. Also useful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name/18024049#18024049)

Comment: If you don't assign `%%p` to a variable but use it immediately, you don't need delayed expansion; of course `echo %%~na_%%p` needs to be inside of the `for /F` loop then, but this doesn't change anything else since it iterates only once anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to link that posted by @Stephan You should use `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before the loop `for...do` and make some tweaks to get the date as `yyyymmdd` :

```bat
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /R %%a IN (*CompactReg00*) DO (
    echo "%%~nxa"
    @for /f %%p in ('wmic  DataFile where "name='C:\\Temp\\Alarm\\Archive\\20200508\\sDiag\\%%~nxa'" get lastmodified   ^| find "+" ') do (
        set "val=%%p"
        echo "!val!"
        set "year=!val:~0,4!"
        set "month=!val:~4,2!"
        set "day=!val:~6,2!"
        echo "%%~na_!val!"
        echo !year!!month!!day!
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: for the desired `YYYYMMDD`, `echo "%%~na_!var:~0,8!"` is sufficient.