# Node.js console.log() in txt file with date and hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, logfile

I want to write into a txt file all the logs of my nodeJs program.

I'm using `node script-file.js >log-file.txt`, but it overwrites the same txt file every time it runs.

Is there a parameter to add so that the title of the generated log-file.txt includes the date and time like this : log-file-18-06-2010-11-57 (dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm)?

Comment: Give [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) a try!

Comment: `>` = overwrite, `>>` = append.

Comment: Thank you @tevemadar, but I'd rather have it generate a new document with the time and date than continue writing to the same file

Comment: How about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a friend of mine, I was able to answer my question.

As the solution `node script.js > log.txt 2> errors.txt` generates only one file of logs and one file of errors. Putting `>>` instead of `>` permit to append the logs and errors, but the notion of time is lost.

The SOLUTION is to simply do `node script.js >> log-error.txt 2>&1` and it generates one file, where both logs and errors are transcribed into this file.
You have to console.log the date at the top of the script and it makes a reliable log-errors file.
To add the date (it will help beginners) just write this :
`var today = new Date(); console.log(today.getDate() + '-' + today.getMonth() + '-' + today.getFullYear() + '  ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds() + '.' + today.getMilliseconds())`

Answer (score 1):

How about using package? I think this is very simple way.
Here's the awesome [log file package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-to-file)

Comment: I tried the "log file package", but it only writes what we put between brackets. If we put `log('Some data');` we will have a default.log file generated with only "Some data" written in it.
I'm looking to copy the logs on the terminal (the console.logs and the errors) on this document