# In a DOS dir, list timedate of files including seconds (in the format "hh:mm:ss" instead of "hh:mm")

Tags: directory, dos, seconds, filetime

I need to save the file index of an MS-DOS folder, keeping the full date/time of any file, including seconds (hh:mm:ss).

With the simple dir command, I can easily do that without seconds (hh:mm). For example, in this way:

```
dir > mylist.txt
```

...I can get this:

```
06/02/2001  16:27           466.114 file1.zip
29/12/2003  17:47            14.331 file2.zip
```

...but, unfortunately, I really need seconds.

For me it's not a trouble to rewrite any result in a presentable way, eliminating unwanted attributes (such as filesize, random spaces etc...) or swapping columns, using RegExp, I already have UltraEdit for that.

Any ideas on how I could add seconds to the list?

I can install third-part software if needed...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you really referring to the old text based operating system DOS / MS-DOS from the early eighties of the last century, or rather the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) (often falsely called "DOS-prompt")? For DOS, the answer is most probably "No" (I'm not sure, if the seconds are actually stored in DOS/FAT). `Cmd.exe` in Windows is much more powerful and the answer is a clear "[yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082)" (although you need some code and `wmic` is deprecated, and not guaranteed to be there on a fresh Install of Windows. But then, `cmd.exe` is deprecated too)

Comment: That file were written with MS-DOS, I was reading them with MS-DOS, but I can easily read that disk with Windows 11, so no problem: I can use CMD if it can help.
I already have Total Commander (and Nir Commander too!), but I couldn't solve the problem with none of them (I would really appreciate a solution with them!).
I tried to read the other solution you linked, but I'm not sure I understood how it works.
If I import everything on Windows 11 keeping the exact file dates (that's not a big trouble, Total Commander can help me with that), what can I write in the .bat file for cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite comprehend your problem. Looks like you have some storage device used with MS-DOS. And now you try to get from that file timestamps in hh:mm:ss format?

Good thing first: MS-DOS stores time with a 2secs resolution. So you "just" lack of a tool reading it out and displaying it. E.g. DIR will only show hh:mm.

I understand that you somewhat favour Total Commander? I have it on my machine but
actually don't use it. But is seems you can add USER DEFINED columns and choose their format including hh:mm:ss. See screenshot below (sorry it's in German).

PS: another option (from 1000 possible) is to write your own "DIR" e.g. with Perl which might be a 10-line script...

[image]